# Ip camera not detected in opencv 3.2 and Java

Tags: java, opencv

Have anyone able to use ip camera with open cv with Java. I used the below code which was working fine for the web camera. But when i Tried to use a ip cam it was not working

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.Image;
import com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils;
import com.wso2telco.rnd.ui.DashBoard;
import com.wso2telco.rnd.ui.UI;

public class TestIPCamera {

private static final long SLEEP_TIME = 1000;
private static VideoCapture camera;
private static FaceComparer comparer;
private static UI ui;
private static DashBoard dashUi;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    comparer = new FaceComparer();

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    //nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadLocally();
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java320");

    camera = new VideoCapture();
    camera.open("http://192.168.1.2:8080/video?video=x.mpjeg");
    System.out.println(camera.isOpened());
    while(!camera.isOpened()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (!camera.isOpened()) {
        System.out.println("Camera Error");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Camera Ready");
        ui = new UI();
        dashUi = new DashBoard();

    }
    while(true){
        runImage();
    }
}
```

I tried many suggestions given in other threads but couldn't find a concrete answer for the issue.

Comment: Have checked whether the camera and your computer are in the same subnet?

Comment: Yes I can aces via browser but not through the code

Comment: Have you granted permissions to java for the firewall?

Comment: Yes AWS connection code is working fine

Comment: And you're not getting any errors nor logs back from this code?

Comment: System.out.println(camera.isOpened());
 this prints false :(

Comment: I've read a bit of the documentation which seems extremely poor, been looking at: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/videoio/VideoCapture.html




EDITED: I've looked a bit more and it looks like you should be able to access the camera through the network with this. Try these:
`VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture("http://192.168.1.2:8080/video.mjpeg");

VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture("http://192.168.1.2:8080/video.cgi?.mjpg");`

Comment: try those new urls

Comment: Android Ip cam app support this url only 
http://192.168.1.2:8080/video

so i tried with this http://192.168.1.2:8080/video?.mjpg no luck :(

Comment: In this case I would try to access that endpoint through a webbrowser and try to check that the endpoint you're using is actually providing data of some sort. Once you're 100% sure that the endpoint you're hitting is the correct one then start checking other stuff like firewalls, antivirus and such. Also make sure it's http and not https protocol. I'd also suggest to read the manufacturer's manual or documentation of some sort... Good luck

Comment: also check if what you need is an http or an rmtp protocol on the url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184976/discussion-between-sheshan-gamage-and-some-random-it-boy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Trying different options Finally i resolved the issue by installing the Open CV 3.4.1 version the issue got resolved.

When you install open cv it shows an output like below. there you can check that **FFMPEG:** is stated as **NO** This configuration stops the code of using the IP cams in the code. To avoid this mis configuration you need install Open CV with the **-D WITH_FFMPEG=ON ..** to solve this problem

```
    --   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann hdf imgproc ml objdetect phase_unwrapping photo plot reg surface_matching video xphoto bgsegm dnn face freetype fuzzy img_hash imgcodecs shape videoio xobjdetect highgui superres ts bioinspired dpm features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo structured_light tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco java optflow stitching python3
--     Disabled:                    world contrib_world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev python2 viz cnn_3dobj cvv dnn_modern matlab sfm
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 3.x:                    YES (ver 3.20.9)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.50.2)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.25)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.6)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2.2.0)
--     GDAL:                        NO
--     GDCM:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.4)
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                    NO
--       avformat:                   NO
--       avutil:                     NO
--       swscale:                    NO
--       avresample:                 NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     Aravis SDK:                  NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     Intel Media SDK:             NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.4 interface 9005)
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use Intel IPP:               2017.0.2 [2017.0.2]
--                at:               /home/hao/opencv-3.3.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
--     Use Intel IPP IW:            prebuilt binaries (2017.0.2)
--     Use Intel IPP Async:         NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Lapack:                  NO
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.3.4)
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use OpenVX:                  NO
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
--     Include path:                /home/hao/opencv-3.3.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 (ver 2.7.12)
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.2+)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.12.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.5/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.7)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               YES
--     Java tests:                  YES
-- 
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/hao/opencv-3.3.0/build
--
```